# Can I query relations using an INNER JOIN instead of two queries in Eloquent?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Can I write something like this:

```php
$post = Post::join(['author'])->find($postId);
$authorName = $post->author->name;
```

To produce only ONE select with inner join (no 2 selects) and without using DB query builder

```sql
SELECT
  post.*, 
  author.*
FROM post
  INNER JOIN author 
    ON author.id = post.author_id
WHERE post.id = ?
```

Comment: So the relation `$this->belongsTo('Author')` will produce 2 `Select` queries. And I want to get author info in the same sql-query with post.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in Eloquent using the `join` method:

```php
$post = Post::join('author', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('author.id', '=', 'post.author_id');
    })
    ->where('post.id', '=', $postId)
    ->select('post.*', 'author.*')
    ->first();
```

Please note that your results in `$post` will be an object where their attributes will correspond to the result set, *if two columns has the same name it will be merged*. This happen when using:

```php
->select('post.*', 'author.*')
```

To avoid this, you should create alias to those columns in the select clause as shown below:

```php
->select('post.id AS post_id', 'author.id AS author_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Post::join('author',function($join){
  $join->on('author.id','=','post.author_id');
})->where('post.id','=',$postId)->select('post.*','author.*');
```

Comment: Just to inform that if two columns share the same name it will be merged. To avoid this, the select clause should contains aliases for those columns.